# Listing in one container different type of objects in react

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

I have an array of objects like so:

```
[{
  "message": {
    "from": "one",
    "body": "lorem"
  }
},
{
  "message": {
    "from": "two",
    "body": "ipsum"
  }
},
{
  "point": {
    "topic": "lorem",
  }
}]
```

How should I render them so that I get the objects in their order and between the appropriate  or  like while message objects are coming, they are inserted into that ul sequentially but when a point object comes, it opens its ul and adds point objects until again message objects are coming and so forth...

This how my render code looks like now, and I don't know how to make it work out as explained above:

```
render: function() {
        var dMessages = sections.map(function(section, i) {
            if (section.hasOwnProperty('message')){
            return <Message key={i} id={i} message={section.message} />;
            }
            if (section.hasOwnProperty('point')){
            return <Point key={i} id={i} point={section.point} />;
            }
        });

        return (
        <div className="main">
          <ul className="message">
            {dMessages}
          </ul>
        </div>);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't twist my mind to solve it with the json object stucture given in the question but only by adding a container array for the message objects, the whole issue seems to be easily resolvable in react way.

New structure:

```
[{ "dialog": [
{
  "message": {
    "from": "one",
    "body": "lorem"
  }
},
{
  "message": {
    "from": "two",
    "body": "ipsum"
  }
}
]},
{
  "point": {
    "topic": "lorem",
  }
}]
```

New render function:

```
render: function() {
        var debateMessages = sections.map(function(section, i) {
            if (section.hasOwnProperty('dialog')){
            return <Dialog key={i} id={i} dialog={section.dialog} />;
            }
            if (section.hasOwnProperty('point')){
            return <Point key={i} id={i} point={section.point} />;
          }
        });

        return (
        <div className="main">
            {dMessages}
        </div>);
    }
```